# Difference between Azure Reddis Cache and Azure CDN

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching, azure-cdn, azure-redis-cache

I need to implement a cache in my application using Azure Cache for Reddis but I went to some blogs where I have an option to store my responses or data using Azure CDN.

Could someone suggest me what is the difference between them?

As per my understanding Reddis is used to store the cache data whereas CDN used to cache data as well as a faster response from the nearby server

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Azure Redis Cache

[image]

It perfectly complements `Azure` database services such as `Cosmos DB`. It provides a cost-effective solution to scale read and write throughput of your data tier. Store and share database query results, session states, static contents, and more using a common cache-aside pattern.

Here is the diagram below of **Cache-Aside Pattern on Azure Storage**.
[image]

We can see that we need to first hit to Redis Cache to see if we have our item available. if so, we will fetch it otherwise, pull the item from Table to re-cache.

> Azure CDN

*“A content delivery network (CDN) is a distributed network of edge servers that can efficiently deliver web content to users. CDNs store cached content on edge servers in point-of-presence (POP) locations that are close to end users, to minimize latency. A CDN profile, belonging to one Azure subscription, can have multiple CDN endpoints.”*

- [What is a content delivery network on Azure?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-overview) @Microsoft

[image]
It lets you reduce load times, save bandwidth, and speed responsiveness—whether you’re developing or managing websites or mobile apps, or encoding and distributing streaming media, gaming software, firmware updates, or IoT endpoints.

[Web-Queue-Worker on Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/architecture-styles/web-queue-worker#web-queue-worker-on-azure-app-service)

[image]

> Conclusion

**Azure Cache for Redis** stores session state and other data that needs low latency access.
**Azure CDN** is used to cache static content such as images, CSS, or HTML.

Comment: So I am bit in doubt what would perform better: Lets say you have an Redis cache with a relatively static JSON (10MB), updates a few tims over the day. Mostly a big fat customer data set. Now this is cached in Memory on server. Would there be a performance gain when moving to Redis cache (besides the fact for other instances etc) or would a CDN (which we also already have in place) a better performance gain? (BTW: also looking into the API management layer from azure to cache results)

Just talking numbers and not perse the best case, pros and cons. :)